# Single quotes in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Any idea why this `Select IN` does not work when I hard code values in a variable?

```
set quoted_identifier off

declare @IPAddressList   varchar(100)

Select @IPAddressList = "'108.61.51.101', '206.221.181.5'"   -- double quotes surrounding single quoted IP addresses

Select @IPAddressList  --- this shows as is:   '108.61.51.101', '206.221.181.5'

-- This returns nothing, but expect it to return rows just like the 2nd select below.
Select *
from dbo.DDoSAttacks
where TargetIP IN (@IPAddressList)

-- This does return rows as expected. 
Select *
from DDoSAttacks
where TargetIP IN ('108.61.51.101', '206.221.181.5')

set quoted_identifier on
```

Comment: The `IN` operator expects a **list of values** (int, or strings) - but if you're providing `@IPAddressList varchar(100)`, you're providing **a single string value** ....

Comment: This depends greatly on what database engine you're using. For instance, SQLite uses Pascal-style quoting: `"He said ""Okay."""` and some others use a backslash (`\`) as an escape character.

Comment: If you're sending this as a request in production code you should `prepare` the statement first, that usually handles escaping single quotes if necessary

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using sql server...marc_s...am I not simulating a list in @IPAddressList  --- this shows as is:   '108.61.51.101', '206.221.181.5'   ?

Comment: And what happens if you do "where TargetIP = '108.61.51.101' or TargetIP = '206.221.181.5'"?

Comment: Both of the answers below are correct. Basically you are searching for a row that looks like this  `INSERT INTO ddosattacks VALUES ('''108.61.51.101'', ''206.221.181.5''')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dymanic SQL, like this :

```
declare @sql nvarchar(255)
select @sql='Select * from dbo.DDoSAttacks where TargetIP IN ('+@IPAddressList+')';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

see : [dynamic sql](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Dynamic SQL is just asking for a SQL Injection attack, especially when accessing a table called DDoSAttacks

Comment: I don't think so, because the dynamic SQL code is totally under the developper control. In the actual case, it does not appear that the executed SQL comes from any user input, in the contrary.Of course, dynamic SQL should not be used with data coming from the user input.

Comment: Nicholas...your suggestion worked as applied to this simple example. What really will be happening is that I will be receiving a parameter that contains comma delimited IP addresses. I want to include that parameter  in an IN clause within a larger select.  Such as:    SELECT TargetIP                            
   FROM (
    SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStarted Desc) AS Row,
     TargetIP                                      As TargetIP
    FROM
     DDosAttacks
    WHERE TargetIP IN (@IPAddressList)) AS DDosAttacksRows
   WHERE
    (Row between (1 * 20 - 20) AND (1 * 20 - 1))

Comment: OK, with dynamic SQL, you should indeed be careful to trust your @IPAddressList. Someone could inject something like "select ..." in place of an IP address list.

Comment: Nicholas...the list is not generated from User input...it is programatically derived. So I think I am ok with dynamically creating the sql...thanks for your help.

Comment: One last thing: the inclusion of the IPaddresslist works fine but when I  include other variables, I get an error when executing..> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int...<  Here's the sql: Select @sql= 'SELECT TargetIP, PeakBPS FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStarted Desc) AS Row, TargetIP  As TargetIP,CONCAT(PeakBPS / 1000000000,'' Gbps'')        As PeakBPS FROM DDosAttacks WHERE TargetIP IN ('+@IPAddressList+')) AS DDosAttacksRows WHERE (Row between ('+@PageNumber+' * ('+@PageSize+' - '+@PageSize+')) AND ('+@PageNumber+' * ('+@PageSize+' - 1)))';

Comment: I can hard code numbers in their place it executes fine....for example   (Row between (1 * (20 - 20)) AND (1 * (20 - 1)))';

Answer (score 1):

You need an answer, or else people will keep visiting this question. But Marc_S comment is spot on:

The IN operator expects a list of values (int, or strings) - but if you're providing @IPAddressList varchar(100), you're providing a single string value

If you want it to work, you could create a function that will parse your delimited string into a table, and then do a "IN" on the values in the table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ParseDelimited] 
(
    @ParseString varchar(MAX),
    @Delimiter   varchar(10)
)
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (value varchar(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int, @j int

    declare @lenParseString int;
    set @lenParseString = LEN(@ParseString);

    DECLARE @lenDelimiter int;  
    set @lenDelimiter = LEN(@Delimiter);

    SELECT @i = 1
    WHILE (@i <= @lenParseString)
    BEGIN
        select  @j = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ParseString, @i)
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @j = @lenParseString + 1;
        END

        INSERT @tbl SELECT SUBSTRING(@ParseString, @i, @j - @i)
        SELECT @i = @j + @lenDelimiter
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Then you can use your function like this:

```
select dd.* from 
dbo.DDosAttacks dd 
inner join dbo.fn_ParseDelimited(@IPAddressList,',') lst
on dd.TargetIP = lst.Value
```

Comment: OK..but I thought that it was a list. So how do i change that variable to be a list?

Comment: @user3020047 how do you get the list of IPs in the first place? If you get it from another query you can easily do this without a variable. Otherwise you probably have to do dynamic SQL.

Comment: This particular split function is very slow, as shown in [Aaron Bertrand's](https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup)  article. It's 6x-faster to use an auxiliary numbers table

Comment: What really will be happening is that I will be receiving a parameter that contains comma delimited IP addresses. I want to include that parameter in an IN clause within a larger select. Such as: SELECT TargetIP FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStarted Desc) AS Row, TargetIP As TargetIP FROM DDosAttacks WHERE TargetIP IN (@IPAddressList)) AS DDosAttacksRows WHERE (Row between (1 * 20 - 20) AND (1 * 20 - 1))